# Removing arbiter from primary-secondary-arbiter-arbiter mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-arbiter

I have a PSA (primary, secondary, arbiter) cluster on 4.4 which was working fine, however I managed to accidentally connect a second arbiter. I've tried to remove this arbiter from the primary using:

- `rs.remove(<host>)`
- `rs.remove(<host>, {force: true})`
- `rs.reconfig(confWithout2ndArbiter)`
- `rs.reconfig(confWithout2ndArbiter, {force: true})`

but all give the following error:

```
{
...
        "errmsg" : "Rejecting reconfig where the new config has a PSA topology and the secondary is electable, but the old config contains only one writable node. Refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfigForPSASet/ for next steps on reconfiguring a PSA set.",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
...
```

I've read the linked article, however my case does not fall under either of the cases where `rs.reconfigForPSASet` should be used and doesn't look relevant for this problem.

Does anyone know how I can remove this member?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set `votes: 0` on the arbiter, then it should work. Maybe you have to set `priority: 0, votes: 0` also (temporary) at the SECONDARY.

Comment: thanks @WernfriedDomscheit, a good idea, but unfortunately this doesn't work: "Arbiter must vote (cannot have 0 votes)", even when forcing reconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to resolve this in the end by looking through the [MongoDB source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v4.4/src/mongo/db/repl/repl_set_config_checks.cpp#L296). Fix was to temporarily change the priority of the secondary to 0, then remove the rogue arbiter, then change the priority of the secondary back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If using MongoDB 5.3 or later forbid multiple arbiters with
`mongod --setParameter allowMultipleArbiters=false`
You could also try a forceful reconfiguration of the replica set:
`rs.reconfig(confWithout2ndArbiter, {force : true})`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion cris, unfortunately the force reconfig gives the same error message, and this is a 4.4 cluster - have updated question accordingly